# Using the Holdout name value pair in matlab's classification tree

Tags: matlab, machine-learning

I am trying to create a classification tree using the holdout training method with the following line in matlab:

```
t = ClassificationTree.fit(x,y,'Prune', 'off', 'SplitCriterion', 'deviance', 'Holdout', 0.2);
pre = predict(t,x)
```

But I get the error

```
??? Undefined function or method 'predict' for input arguments of type
'classreg.learning.partition.ClassificationPartitionedModel'.
```

Could anyone please help me with this? I am having trouble figuring out how to go about predicting when using the Holdout name value pair in the classification tree(or a Kfold one). That is should I give the predict function x and it will automatically figure out to run the test on 20 percent of the data? I have tried looking it up but can't find a lot of documentation on it. Would very much appreciate any help.

EDIT: I figured this out, if anyone is interested. Its the [kfoldPredict](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/classificationpartitionedmodel.kfoldpredict.html) method.